# Using py2exe, how to create an executable usng python and tkinter?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, executable, py2exe

I'm trying to turn a program that I've written in Python 2.7 (using tkinter for the GUI) into a standalone executable using py2exe.  I've written the following script in a file called setup.py:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe
setup(data_files=['C:\Python27\tcl\tcl8.5\init.tcl'] , windows = ["Brand_Counter.py"])
```

When I run this, the command prompt opens for a second, then nothing happens.  As far as I can tell, according to the documentation my code should create a subdirectory "dist" which will contain my executable, but this isn't happening.  Does anybody see anything wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do a build of a py2exe project, you should issue this command from the directory that contains your setup.py file:

```
python setup.py py2exe
```

Works well for me.

EDIT ---

In addition you're using the data_files parameter which takes a list of tuples. Your parameter should look something like this:

```
data_files=[('tclfiles', ['C:\Python27\tcl\tcl8.5\init.tcl'])]
```

Adjusted for wherever you want to place your init.tcl file. For more examples see this link: [py2exe data_files](http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/data_files)

Comment: When I try this, I get a syntax error that says the following:    File "<stdin>", line 1 python setup.py py2exe    In the error message there is an arrow (^) below the "p" in the word "setup".  Does this happen when you run it?  Any suggestions would be hugely appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: No I don't get that. Are you sure you're in the same directory as your setup.py file? OTOH, I am only using the console parameter to setup. If you're sure you're in the right directory, can you edit your question to include the exact error message?

Comment: Never mind, I think I see the problem. data_files takes a list of tuples. Each tuple contains a location to store and a location to copy from. See this link for examples: [Py2exe data_files](http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/data_files)